# PHP word replacement using regular expression

Tags: php

Halo, I am trying to replace a complete word by constants values in php using `preg_replace` `'\b'` but I am getting the error.

Following is my code snippet:

```
<?php
    $refinedName = str_replace(explode(",", Constants::$master_refine_categories[$_GET["category"]]), '',$refinedName);

    foreach ($refinedName as $item) {
        $item = preg_replace('/\b$item\b/','',$refinedName);            
    }
?>
```

Comment: what  error message you get?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: can you show `var_dump(Constants::$master_refine_categories[$_GET["category"]])` and `var_dump($refinedName)` before replacement?

Comment: @Rashmi: Please include the information from these comments (or there answers) in the question and then flag those comments as 'obsolete'. This would improve and concretize the format of your question.